# Data not loading in the required format

Tags: r

I am loading the dataset from a csv file with numbers.

```
83178386964
60635478879
56933477540
62821544924
72770566465
and so on..
```

But after passing `summary(w)` command I am not getting the proper summary results like mean and median. It is giving results like

```
X83178386963.63 
Mode:logical
NA's:0`
```

Can anyone help me I need data in the normal form. I am getting `x83178386964` when I pass `w` command.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no header in your .csv file, but R is treating your first row of data as a header.

So in your `read.csv()` call I would put `header=FALSE`.

Also, you may want to try `read.table()` in this scenario, considering there are actually no comma separated values in your file.

Comment: How to add a header to the dataframe ? Now my data is getting stored as V183178386964, V2 60635478879 ..and so on .How to find the length now of all the Vs?